# How to write 'if not caught' code in a Try Catch

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

Wondering if the following can be done in a simple way:

```
Try
  Some Statements
Catch ex As ...
  Error handling stuff
NotCatch
  Code to handle *only* if there was no Catch
End Try
```

A Finally bloc will not do it, because it is executed even if the Catch was executed. Putting the code after the End Try doesn't work either, as it's always executed. I tried to place an Exit Try after the Error handling stuff, but then nothing is executed any more before the End Try.

Is there an clean and easy way to do this without variables to remember that the Catch was executed?

Comment: Put it in a function which returns a bool indicating if the Catch was tripped

Answer (score 1):

The normal way is like this:

```
Try
  Some Statements
  Code to handle *only* if there was no Catch
Catch ex As ...
  Error handling stuff
End Try
```

This works because as soon as an exception is thrown, control jumps to the catch block and the rest of the try block is ignored. Or to put it another way: If a line in the "try" runs, then you know there hasn't been an exception yet.

If you have other requirements that means this wont work then you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: But at that point, I can't know yet if there will be a catch or not - at that position, the code will _always_ be executed, whereas the goal is to execute _only_ if the catch was _not_ executed.

Comment: If Some Statements throws an error, the rest won't execute

Comment: Okay... that's indeed not very complicated, but I didn't think about this. Thanks, @John3136, neat trick.

Comment: @CeSinge It isn't a trick at all, its just the standard way of handling exceptions ;-)